# Dying house bamboo

Tags: houseplants, bamboo

I’ve had these bamboo plants for about 6 months now and they have recently started dying,I have noticed a few really tiny bugs crawling around in the soil. Does anyone have a clue on why it’s dying and what are these insects?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Could it also be weather change as I lived near sea and have moved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, is it possible to take  photos of the bugs?